# Mutual Authentiction on HTTPS with Wordpress HTTP API?

Tags: http-api

I'm currently building a prototype to post data from Wordpress to a Rightmove RESTful JSON API (a rental/property website in the UK - specifically the Real Time Datafeed)

Was pretty impressed that Wordpress had the HTTP API actually, but upon digging deeper I've realised it seems to be lacking a fair few things (documentation being one!)

Does the HTTP API support mutual authentication and SSL in any way? Specifically the mutual authentication part?  As this is a requirement of the API given the sensitive nature of the data.

All I can find is that it can support SSL but nothing to do with client certificates, and basic authentication.

I'm far from an expert in these things but I'm thinking I need to go down the pure PHP route using fsock/curl

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Re the WP HTTP API look for the `sslverify` and `sslcertificates` args in this docs page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/. `sslverify` defaults to `true` and `sslcertificates` accepts an absolute path to a certificate file.

If you're going to be doing a lot of lifting with this API (sounds like it for a real estate site), I would suggest considering the popular PHP library Guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

You will likely save yourself headaches over anything with fsock/curl. Many WP plugins use Guzzle under the hood. It's well-documented, has tons of examples online, and supports the sort of functionality that you need. It can be installed via composer: `composer require guzzle/guzzle`

Seeing as your primary concern is authentication with a certificate, when you instantiate a new `GuzzleHttp\Client`, include the `cert` and `ssl_key` args:

See:

- http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cert
- http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#ssl-key